# Something like shared NSUserDefaults and App Groups in watchOS 2?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, ios-app-group, watchos-2

I am currently updating an app of mine for watchOS 2 and got some trouble with communication between the devices: previously I had been using shared NSUserDefaults to enable both the Watch and the iOS device to read and write several values from one App Group independently.

Now that watchOS 2 apps are running natively on the Watch and the Watch Connectivity Framework replaced previous communication options, this no longer seems applicable. However, from what I read on the reference, implementing the same functionality I had in watchOS 1 with Watch Connectivity is rather cumbersome…

Is there any other option for me to create some sort of container/file/database/whatsoever that I can access and update from both my Watch app and the related iOS app?

Comment: If you only want to read from the `NSUserDefaults` on your Apple Watch then you can still use App Groups to do this. Check out the watch settings programming guide for a little more info about how it works: https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/Settings.html

Comment: Ok, cool. This might be useful for a different app I still have to update for watchOS 2. 
In this case, though, I needed to read and write, so I switched from App Groups to using the Watch Connectivity framework which (after some troubleshooting) worked quite well. Now the value I need on both devices is stored in the NSUserDefaults on both the Watch and the iOS-device separately and whenever one device has to make a change to it, a userInfo-Dictionary is sent to the other device where the value is then changed, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With watchOS 2 both the WatchKit App and Extension run natively on Apple Watch, so even if you use shared user defaults or app groups the data you put inside them will be on the watch and so not accessible from the iOS app.

To send data to the watch you can use the WatchConnectivity framework, or use a NSURLSession to download data from a server if that's your case.

Comment: Thanks :) I'll have to figure out a way to make the functionality work with the Watch Connectivity framework then...